# How to make an immutable BusinessLayer in Controller without change its properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have BusinessLayer which contains Collections and reusable code in an old desktop app.

Now I want to use this layer again in an MVC app.
I try to use the layer in Controller for example Index()

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["DataEntryLogic"] == null)
        Session["DataEntryLogic"] = new DataEntryLogic();

    var EntryLogic = Session["DataEntryLogic"] as DataEntryLogic;

    EntryLogic.Tables.Add(new Table());
    EntryLogic.Tables[0].TableID = "AccTransHed";
    EntryLogic.Tables[0].TableType = TableType.Master;
}
```

Now I want to keep the tables I added in the first View load. and make it immutable in next post-backs. I used Session. I don't know if ViewBag or ViewData should be used instead.

In short: Which pattern should I follow for making immutable BusinessLayer?

Because every time post-backs happened idon't need to get table information or keys or the Logic itself again and again.

**Updated 2019/04/14**

Should i replace entire BusinessLogic properties and collections to this pattern ?

in Windows app:

```
pulic class EntryLogic{
   public List<Table> Tables{get;set;}
}
```

To MVC app:

```
public class EntryLogic{
  public List<Table> Tables{
    get{
           if(Session["Tables"] == null)
              Session["Tables"] = new List<Table>();
           return Session["Tables"] as List<Table>;
      }
    set { Session["Tables"] = value;}
  }
}
```

Or Just initialize instance of EntryLogic of desktop app in a session variable ?

```
var EntryLogic = Session["EntryLogic"] as EntryLogic;
```

Comment: Session and ViewBag are not good tools for doing such a job. For a fast and simple solution, you can use the "Singleton" pattern.

Comment: i updated the question to add more points. i don't know which is good pattern ? convert entire layer properties to sessions or just add session of that layer and works with properties directly

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think that you want to use the layer on index but on app start. Also if you are gonna use Session this means that each user will have a different set of tables.

It boils down to:

- Are the collections the same for each user?
  If they are then you want to initialize them in app start
- Also having static variables is the same. By using a static variable it will be shared among all the actions and users.
- If each user has a different set of tables and keys and they are distinct then yes Session can be used to store any variable you want.

Also:

- **ViewBag** and **ViewData** are the same. You can use either.

This is you static class with the collection

[image]

This is where you initialize and populate the collection

[image]

And this how you use your collection to the controllers.

[image]

Comment: OK. should i rewrite the entry LogicLayer and replace the collection to Session["Collection"] and all variables to this pattern ? or just add LogicLayer Instance inside a Session state itself?

Comment: The EntryLogic must be not changed and its same for all users. and for entire applications. it must appeard like windows app.

Comment: Then you will create a static class that will hold those collections, the static class will be initialized at app start. If you used session then the same collection would appear for each user.

Comment: I don't need to creating more stuff. its already created. but the BusinessLogic itself is a class. read updated above in question. Each view have its own instance of EntryLogic class which contains the table definations

Comment: How is it created? It's clearly not otherwise you wouldn't be initializing again as it seems. Also Session is different for each user. Session is a no go. If you had 100 items and 1000 users then you would end up with a number of items = 100*1000. The code you supplied doesn't initializes anything or is creating anything. There are no data.

Comment: the code i write is an example. for example i have Collection of string in old desktop. as you know desktop is immutable by default. unlike MVC is stateless . so should i convert this collection to ViewData["Collection"] or convert entire class to ViewData["LogicClass"]

Comment: OK, but looks like the collection will still mutable after first use. so every post or get it will still re-created. and all i need is Each view have instance of SomeClass this class contains some collections which initialized only once. and then any access to its collections can easily and get properties.

Comment: waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah ?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you can use caching to reduce the calls to the database and not worry about preserving the state.